# How to verify a specific user password in oracle 6i?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I want to make oracle 6i form to change `DBA_USERS`, I already finished it but I cannot check if Old Password is valid or not.

I Googled about that but I didn`t find any thing to do the password verification.

So, I want to know how to do that in oracle 6i forms with PL/SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle forms have `Get_Application_Property` builtin. Use it to get property `PASSWORD` - you will get password provided by user when connecting to forms application:

```
declare
  p_password Varchar2(255);
begin
  p_password := Get_Application_Property(PASSWORD);

  -- now do your test 
  ...
end;
```

Comment: What if I want to change another account password not the current

Comment: I'm afraid the only chance is to write an external routine to check connection using provided password and call it by <code>host</code> command

Comment: I recommend to check use case. Why do you check old password of other user? You should not  know it?

Comment: I prepare form to allow users change their current password

Comment: They are logged by other account? I would let them log in by their current password and then change it.

Comment: Thier account is not a DBA

Comment: oracle users don't need special privileges to change own passwords. They can simply use `ALTER USER old_password PASSWORD new_password`.